# Can we discuss steampunk here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I definitely think steampunk has a place under sci-fi but wanted to ask before starting any possible discussions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Steampunk usually involves some kind of alternate history of technological development so it is feels closer to science fiction than it does it fantasy. I don't see a good reason to exclude it.

Comment: [We seem to have decided that fantasy is in anyway.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-fantasy-in-spec-for-this-site/10#10)

Answer (score 6):

Steampunk, like the other "punks" is one of those hate-it-or-leave it genres. I like it, and I consider it "on topic" as it tends towards "alternate histories."

Answer (score 3):

I'm not generally fond of steampunk myself, but I would agree that it's on-topic.